# CircleCi: how to run workflow only when triggered by API?

Tags: circleci

This is an extract of my config.yml file for CircleCi:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  
  deploy:  
    when: << pipeline.parameters.run_workflow_deploy >>
    jobs:
      - deploy:          
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
```

So I want to trigger my "deploy" job only on API calling. It works very well.

But CircleCi triggers automatically the workflow when some changes on the master branch, and here you are the message on CircleCi backoffice:

[image]

How avoid this automatic trigger from CircleCi?

Answer (score 3):

Workflows on CircleCI are triggered on every `git push` by default. From [documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/triggers/) -

> By default, CircleCI automatically builds a project whenever you push changes to a version control system (VCS).

You can override this using the `[skip ci]` tag in the commit. See [skip-build documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/triggers/#skip-builds)

Comment: Is there a way to set this as default off, and then specifically run the build with something like `[ci]`?

Answer (score 3):

don't know if you are stil looking for an answer but... I managed to do it using parameters.

You create your branch parameter in your config.yml file:

```yaml
version: 2.1
parameters: 
    git-branch: 
      default: non-existing-branch
      type: string
```

and add a filter on the workflow job:

```yaml
filters:
  branches:
     only:
        - << pipeline.parameters.git-branch >>
```

So, the pipeline will not start on any commits, since it defaults to the non-existing-branch.

But then, you can pass the parameter in your API in the body.

```
"parameters": {
     "branch-name": "develop"
}
```

This will actually trigger the pipeline to start correctly.

Comment: a very cool way to do it. this helped me. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add default values for your parameters as follows:

```yaml
parameters:
  run_workflow_deploy:
    default: false
    type: boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also configure your logical statement (at the workflow or step level) using the built-in `pipeline.trigger_source` pipeline value (https://circleci.com/docs/pipeline-variables/#pipeline-values).